# Postgres: QueryFailedError: type "http_response" does not exist. Unable to call HTTP function as a custom user

Tags: sql, postgresql, nestjs, supabase

I was trying out supabase + nestjs REST API. But for some weird reasons, HTTP trigger is not working.

We wanted to call our API end point whenever `INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE` operations happen in the table.

We looked into supabase webhook, but since it is still in alpha, we could not use it.

So we thought of using [Postgres HTTP extension](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http)

Here's the step which i have followed.

```sql
create user api_gateway with password 'dummypassword';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO api_gateway;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO api_gateway;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO api_gateway;
GRANT all ON SCHEMA net TO api_gateway;
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO api_gateway;
grant usage ON schema extensions TO api_gateway;
```

Then i created a table in public schema as follows

```sql
create table test(
  id uuid PRIMARY KEY not null DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  created_at timestamp with time zone default current_timestamp not null,
  name varchar(50)
);
```

Then i created trigger in following format

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_post()
returns trigger as $$

declare hres http_response;
declare trigger_payload jsonb;

begin
  trigger_payload = jsonb_build_object(
    'old_record', OLD,
    'record', NEW,
    'type', TG_OP,
    'table', TG_TABLE_NAME,
    'schema', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA
  );

  select * into hres from http(
    (
      'POST',
      'my rest endpoing',
      ARRAY[
        http_header('Authorization', concat('Bearer ', 'my token')),
        http_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      ],
      trigger_payload,
      trigger_payload
    )::http_request
    );

  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;


DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ON_CREATE_test on "public"."test";
CREATE TRIGGER ON_CREATE_test
AFTER INSERT ON public.test
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.test_post();
```

Then i ran the following query

```sql
GRANT ALL ON FUNCTION public.publish_to_pubsub() TO api_gateway;
```

Now, when i manually insert a row into the Test table from supabase dashboard, the trigger executes and the REST api request is made.

But when i connect to supabase from nestjs (using type orm module, api_gateway as user) and make a post request to insert a row into test table, i get following error.

`QueryFailedError: type "http_response" does not exist`

Detailed log

```
{
    length: 721,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '42704',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: '16',
    internalQuery: '\n' +
      '\n' +
      'declare hres http_response;\n' +
      'declare trigger_payload jsonb;\n' +
      '\n' +
      'begin\n' +
      '  trigger_payload = jsonb_build_object(\n' +
      "    'old_record', OLD,\n" +
      "    'record', NEW,\n" +
      "    'type', TG_OP,\n" +
      "    'table', TG_TABLE_NAME,\n" +
      "    'schema', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA\n" +
      '  );\n' +
      '\n' +
      '  select * into hres from http(\n' +
      '    (\n' +
      "      'POST',\n" +
      "      'https://api***********************************',\n" +
      '      ARRAY[\n' +
      "        http_header('Authorization', concat('Bearer ', '')),\n" +
      "        http_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')\n" +
      '      ],\n' +
      '      trigger_payload,\n' +
      '      trigger_payload\n' +
      '    )::http_request\n' +
      '    );\n' +
      '\n' +
      '  return new;\n' +
      'end;\n',
    where: 'compilation of PL/pgSQL function "test_post" near line 3',
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'parse_type.c',
    line: '270',
    routine: 'typenameType'
  }
```

Not really sure what the issue is. I am happy to provide any additional information.

Comment: Could it be the following line where you have the wrong function name? "GRANT ALL ON FUNCTION public.publish_to_pubsub() TO api_gateway;"

Comment: @dshukertjr Ahh, yeah. I did not notice that!